# What jQuery selector should I use to select a div class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

```
<div id="stage-1" class="stage">
    <div class="section">
        <section>
            <h3 class="formHeader">Choose a category</h3>
            <ul id="formNav">
                <li>
                    <h4>Bathrooms, Kitchens, Bedrooms &amp; Furniture</h4>
                    <div class="js-reveal">

                    </div>
                </li>
           </ul>
       </section>
   </div>
```

I am trying to select the `.js-reveal` element. What jQuery selector should I use to select it?

Comment: Why do you have `<div class="section"><section>`? It's a pleonasm

Comment: @Oriol: Thanks for showing me "pleonasm". I'm going to add that to my word vocabulary. ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Use **.(class name)**:

```
$('.js-reveal').text('Selected');
```

Please also note that you missed the closing square bracket in your `</div>` at the end.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

***HTML***

```
<div id="stage-1" class="stage">
    <div class="section">
        <section>
            <h3 class="formHeader">Choose a category</h3>
            <ul id="formNav">
                <li>
                    <h4>Bathrooms, Kitchens, Bedrooms &amp; Furniture</h4>
                    <div class="js-reveal">
                            Hello world
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </section>
    </div>
</div>
```

***JS CODE***

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     /*to get html element*/
       alert($('.js-reveal').html());
});

$(document).ready(function(){
     /*to get containing text*/
       alert($('.js-reveal').text());
});
```

Comment: @user1689607 I've vote you up after a simple modication.Please make a revivew. thanks